# AJAX Jquery: execution order of events

Tags: ajax, event-handling, jquery

I have a webpage with different elements (a list of links and two select boxes) connected between them. Clicking on them may affect one of the other element and all of their values contribuite to update a value to show on the page.

So, the code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var someVar = '';

    $("select#size").bind('change', function() {
        someVar = $(this).val();
        console.log('first');
    });

    my_change();
    console.log('second' + someVar);
});

function my_change() {

    $.getJSON("photos/change_product", {json_stuff}, function(data) {
        var options = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
            options.push('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].label + '</option>');
        }
        $("select#size").trigger('change');
        $("select#options").html(options.join('')).trigger('change');
    })
};

};
```

When I load the page the `my_change` function is called. It does some stuff and then triggers a `change event` on a select-box. I need to update a value using what's inside this select box and only then let the execution to proceed. So what I need this code to do would be to print 'first', and then 'second' with the value of the variable. What actually happen is that it prints 'second' 'first'.

I think it's because I'm doing asynchronous calls. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'second' `console.log()` is being called first since the asynchronous `$.getJSON()` call waits for the response from the server before firing its callback function. You could save the jqXHR object to a variable and then use that to run your 'second' `consone.log()` with `$.when()`:

```
$(function() {

    var someVar = '';

    $("#size").on('change', function() {//on() is the same as bind() here
        someVar = $(this).val();
        console.log('first');
    });

    //save the jQuery XHR object from your $.getJSON request
    var jqXHR = my_change();

    //when the above jQuery XHR object resolves, it will fire the second console.log
    $.when(jqXHR).then(function () {
        console.log('second' + someVar);
    });
});

function my_change() {

    //here we return the jQuery XHR object for the $.getJSON request so we can run code once it resolves
    return $.getJSON("photos/change_product", {json_stuff}, function(data) {
        var options = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
            options.push('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].label + '</option>');
        }
        $("#size").trigger('change');
        $("#options").html(options.join('')).trigger('change');
    })
};
```

Here is documentation for `$.when()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when

A quick side-note: it is generally slower to add a tag-type to a selector, especially when you are selecting IDs as that is already a very fast method of selecting elements.

Comment: it's still printing 'second' and then 'first'. it seems that even if the `change` event is manually triggered inside the function `my_change`, it is then captured after, don't really know when. I would need to wait for the change to be completed so I can get a value from the select

Comment: @Carlo I just created a test and it appears to be working as expected: http://apexeleven.com/stackoverflow/jquery.when/test.html (click the bar on the bottom of the page to run a test, which you can do multiple times if you want).

Comment: sigh, really don't know what to say. I'm checking and rechecking my code and it looks (almost) the same. At this point I think it maybe something really really stupid, but I can't understand what. I pasted here the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/4V2RX/2/

To me it outputs: second, second, first size, first options 8

Comment: @Carlo Inside the `changeProduct` function you need to return the result of your `$.getJSON()` request by changing `$.getJSON("photos/change_product", json_data, function(data) {` to `return  $.getJSON("photos/change_product", json_data, function(data) {`. You need to return the jqXHR object (like the example in this comment and in my answer) so it can be resolved in the `$.when()` function. Since you are not doing this in your jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/4V2RX/2 ) the `$.when()` function is immediately resolving instead of waiting for the AJAX call to complete.

Comment: @Carlo I updated my example: http://apexeleven.com/stackoverflow/jquery.when/test.html. I commented out some code but that shouldn't affect the AJAX call. All I did was place `return` before the `$.getJSON()` function call like in my above comment.

Comment: oh, great. I knew it was something stupid, but I just couldn't see the missing return in my code. really thanks for your help and patience

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways to do this.

You could use jQuery [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and call the console.log after the ajax response finishes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var someVar = '';

    $("select#size").bind('change', function() {
        someVar = $(this).val();
        console.log('first');
    });

    $.when( my_change() ).then(function(){ 
            console.log('second' + someVar);
    }); 
});

function my_change() {

    return $.getJSON("photos/change_product", {json_stuff}, function(data) {
        var options = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
            options.push('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].label + '</option>');
        }
        $("select#size").trigger('change');
        $("select#options").html(options.join('')).trigger('change');
    })
};

};
```

Or you could add a callback argument to the `my_change(callback)` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var someVar = '';

    $("select#size").bind('change', function() {
        someVar = $(this).val();
        console.log('first');
    });

    my_change(function(){ console.log('second' + someVar) } ); 

});

function my_change(callback) {

    return $.getJSON("photos/change_product", {json_stuff}, function(data) {
        var options = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
            options.push('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].label + '</option>');
        }
        $("select#size").trigger('change');
        if( typeof callback !== 'undefined' && typeof callback === 'function' )
            callback(); 
        $("select#options").html(options.join('')).trigger('change');
    })
};

};
```

Comment: great thanks. still not sure whether I'll use `$.when` or the callback. anyway, at this point, I think I don't need to bind the event anymore

Comment: sorry, checking again this solution is not working. using $.when it happens that it runs first the code inside it, and then it captures the "change" event.

Answer (score 0):

Any code that relies on the response of the `getJSON` must be placed in, or called from, the `getJSON` callback.

That's what a callback is for.

You should note that your `my_change` function will not have access to the `someVar` variable because it is local to the `ready()` callback.

To remedy this, move the `my_change` function inside the `ready()` callback.

Or just pass a function directly to `my_change`.

```
my_change(function() {
    console.log('second' + someVar);
});
```

And have the `getJSON` callback invoke the function.

```
function my_change( func ) {

    $.getJSON("photos/change_product", {json_stuff}, function(data) {
        var options = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
            options.push('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].label + '</option>');
        }
        $("select#size").trigger('change');
        $("select#options").html(options.join('')).trigger('change');

        func();
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the `my_change()` function tries to access the `someVar` variable.

Comment: @Jasper: It doesn't, but the first line of my answer states that any code that relies on the response must be placed in...the callback. So if the `console.log('second' + someVar);` was placed in the callback, it would no longer have access to `someVar`. :)